# TCPDF output indented?

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, html2pdf

I have problem when converting PHP/HTML to PDF using TCPDF.

My method is:

First, I make a buffered HTML file from current PHP process, then I convert that HTML with TCPDF.

But the PDF results differently from what I expected. The first line is indented.

Here is my code:

```
index1.php

<form action="index1-process.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<?php
function loop(){    
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
        echo "Line ".$i."<br />\r\n";
    }   
}
?>

<!-- start buffering -->
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>

<?php loop() ?>

</body>
</html>

<!-- save buffer to file -->
<?php file_put_contents("index1.html", ob_get_contents()); ?>
```

After I clicked in the 'Save' button it buffers to:

```
index1.html

<html>
<body>

Line 0<br />
Line 1<br />
Line 2<br />
Line 3<br />
Line 4<br />
Line 5<br />

</body>
</html>

<!-- save buffer to file -->
```

but the PDF result is indented in first line:

```
index1.pdf

  Line 0
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Here is my process code:

```
index1-process.php

<?php

require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins("10","10","10");

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

$pdf->SetFont("times");

$pdf->AddPage();

$html = file_get_contents("index1.html");

$pdf->writeHTML($html);

$pdf->Output("index1.pdf","D");
```

Is it my method or my code wrong?

Or is there any better way to save a PHP processed page to PDF?

Comment: Check the "blank" line right before `<?php loop() ?>`. You might have a stray tab character or something there.

Comment: wow, thanks for fast response. you are right. i edited my code it's look great now. i have one other question. is there any simple way to convert a PHP processed page to PDF file?

Comment: nope, not really. "quickest" way is to use a headless browser and print-to-pdf type functionality, but it's not pretty.

Comment: so my "method" by buffering it to HTML first and then convert it to PDF is, "acceptable"... right?

Comment: it's one way of going about it. technically you wouldn't need the buffering and could build the page purely with string operations, especially since the output of the entire script will be an invalid html document (nested `<html>` tags are a no-no).

Comment: The delivery of this question is good and detailed but, there's should at least an answer to this question. If the OP finds a solution himself then the OP should give an answer to his question. The answer should be posted to provides information to others who struggle with the same problem.